# How do I change the color of the gap between the cells in the selected row in TableView？

Tags: java, javafx

How do I change the color of the gap between the cells in the selected row in TableView？
[image]

I looked at the javafx css documentation, but nothing came of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom styling for tables is tricky.

You need to define a custom color for the table cell border in a CSS stylesheet and use that color in relevant CSS rules.

```
.root {
    -my-custom-table-cell-border-color: red;
}
/* Constants used throughout the tableview. */
/* default value was: derive(-fx-color,5%); */
.table-view {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: -my-custom-table-cell-border-color;
}
/* Selected rows */
/* default value was: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%) */
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: -my-custom-table-cell-border-color;
}
/* Selected when control is not focused */
/* default value was: derive(-fx-selection-bar-non-focused, 20%); */
.table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: -my-custom-table-cell-border-color;
}
```

Adjust the example as you need for your situation.  For instance, if you only want to change the color for selected rows, then only define the appropriate rules that use the `:selected` psuedoclass.  For the example I use red as the custom color so that is obvious where it is being displayed. For your implementation, you can choose another color or the color `transparent` if you don't want the border to be visible.

Styling for other list type controls like `ListView`, `TreeTableView`, etc is similar to above (they just use different selector names that can be found in the `modena.css` stylesheet).

**Additional Resources**

Resources that you can study and use that may help you to solve similar problems in the future:

- [`modena.css`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L2365), located in the javafx-controls jar file for your JavaFX distribution.
- The [CSS analyzer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/stylesheet-support.htm) in [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).
- The scene graph inspection tool [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view).
- [Eden guide to table view customization](https://edencoding.com/tableview-customization-cellfactory/).
- The [JavaFX CSS reference guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview), though it does not provide enough information to fully customize TableView visual style.

To determine the solution to your question, I first examined the CSS reference guide. As you noted, it was unhelpful in this answer, then I searched `modena.css` for the relevant lookup rules and ran some tests based on applying custom modifications of the style information I found there.